# Cannot export report to excel in crystal reports xi java

Tags: java, swing, export-to-excel, crystal-reports-xi

> How do you add an `export to excel` option on the export button from the `reportviewebean` UI class?

I only have the options `crystal report (rpt)`, `pdf`, `microsoft word` -editable, and `rtf`.

I need it to export my report to excel.